# What should be proven when your claim ends with a clause for a particular case?

Tags: proof-writing

My question is not about how to prove the following proof, as I already know how to do so. What I am more concerned about is the type of claim that is being made, and what am I really being asked to show; in particular when your claim is something relatively generalized, and you are brought to focus on a particular case that may occur within the general one. Below is the particular example of what I am talking about to be a bit more clear:

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n > 0$. Show that $\lfloor\lfloor x \rfloor /n\rfloor = \lfloor x/n \rfloor$; in particular, $\lfloor\lfloor a/b \rfloor /c \rfloor = \lfloor a/bc \rfloor$ for all positive integers $a,b,c$.

I have shown both cases individually, but should I really only be proving the general case and acknowledging the particular case?

Note on tags: Even though the particular problem is that of elementary number theory, I do not believe my question should be tagged as such since my question is not particular to the subject of the question, but more so the form of the question.

Comment: Often you just have to nod to the particular case (i.e. say "from the general case it is clear by choosing $x=a/b$ and $n=c$ that... ".) They are usually mentioned specifically because that particular instance is used a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In instances like this, you should prove the general case, and then show how/why the particular case follows from it (often quite readily). It isn't *wrong* to prove the particular case separately, but it isn't ideal.